# One's wife's or death of beloved ones can be the result of sins committed by ancestors?

Tags: moksha, atma, death, curse

My questions are.

1. Sequential and untimely deaths in a family by accident can be the curse of one's forefathers ?
2. Does one's jeevātmā wanders due to death in young age?
3. Is there any remedy or solution to solve the problem if jeevātmā of one's beloved wandering due to death at young age? Provided it had attachments to its beloved ones as well.
4. Does *Ashtamangala Prashnam* find the reason of deaths?
5. **Is there any remedy to stop sequential deaths in one's family?**

Comment: It may seem sequential or untimely to you, but in reality it is not. All is due to a person's own karma, not to any karma or curse of your forefathers. It may have been your karma to be born this life in a family with many early deaths. Dying early does not mean that a soul wanders. A soul that wanders after death is doing so from their own karma. If a soul is wandering near to you, do Ram Nam. Hanuman will sweep away any lost souls that are nearby where Ram Nam is done and help them on their way.